# XML xpath, get the parent element till a specific element

Tags: xpath, element, parent

I'm looking for the right xpath syntax to get a specific parent of an element.
Example:

```
root
   |- div
   |     |
   |     |----??? ---|
   |     |           |-a [class=1]
   |     |                      |- text[ A TEXT I DON'T WANT]
   |     |
   |     |
   |     |
   |     |-text[THE TEXT]
   |
   |-div 
   |    |-text[THE TEXT I DON'T WANT]
   |
   |-div 
   |    |-text[THE TEXT I DON'T WANT]
```

I want to get the text "THE TEXT" but the one that contains `a [class=1]` inside the same div. Something like this:

```
//div//a[@class=1]/text[contains(.,'A TEXT')]/parent::*/parent::*.... <till div element>  /text
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, exact, short and easy XPath one-liner expression that selects exactly the wanted text node, without using any backward axis at all :)

Comment: Upvote for a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 71):

Given the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <foo id="id1">
        <foo id="i2">
            <baz/>
        </foo>
    </foo>
</root>
```

You can find the *nearest ancestor* foo element from baz using the XPath expression:

```
//baz/ancestor::foo[1]
```

Which will select the foo element node of id "i2".

So in your example (if I understand right) once you have got the "a" element you want, you can get "back up" the tree to the nearest ancestor div by appending "/ancestor::div[1]" to your expression.

Answer (score 10):

**Use**:

```
/root/div[.//a[@class='1']]/text()
```

This selects any text node that is a child of any `a` element that has a `class` attribute with value `'1'`  and that (the `a` element) is a descendent of any `div` element that is a child of the top element named `root`.

Comment: OP needs 'THE TEXT', your expression will retrieve 'A TEXT'

Comment: Good observation -- I guess I hadn'rt understood the question when I answered it one year ago -- fixed now. Please, have a look and reverse your downvote.